# как установить и запустить ssh-сервер в gnu/guix?

Tags: ssh, guix

вот скачал я [qemu-образ gnu/guix](https://guix.gnu.org/download/), распаковал, запустил с [рекомендованным параметром](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Running-Guix-in-a-VM.html#Connecting-Through-SSH) (`-nic user,model=virtio-net-pci,hostfwd=tcp::10022-:22`), догадался, что можно использовать *sudo* для административных действий (по умолчанию запускается x-сессия пользователя guest).

а вот как теперь установить и, главное, запустить openssh-сервер, чтобы можно было по протоколу ssh подключиться с хост-машины? по [рекомендованной ссылке](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Networking-Services.html), честно говоря, ничего не понятно, а система инициализации тут вообще своя собственная: [gnu/shepherd](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Shepherd-Services.html).

вроде бы как вся конфигурации системы должна описываться в одном файле — `/etc/system.scm`, но даже этого файла почему-то нет.

Comment: Тоже пробуете? Guix оборачивает конфигурацию все базовых серивсов в  Guile Scheme и достаточно иметь единый файл описывающий всю систему. https://github.com/Hellseher/wds/blob/master/wds-guix/memo.org#memo-200417140224-how-to-configure-and-run-a-system-service

Comment: @Hellseher, уже скорее нет: разочаровали проблемы с shebang-ами.

Comment: Там с этим немного похитрить нужно, ведь главный ресурс программ это ссылки к `/gnu/store` Есть специальный сервис, где можно прописать все базовые шебанги - `special-files-service-type` https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Base-Services.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

да, действительно, [вся конфигурация системы](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/System-Configuration.html) может описываться всего одним файлом (на языке *scheme*). и прямо в этом файле можно дать указание использовать openssh-сервер (он будет и установлен и запущен после применения новой конфигурации). в «образцовом» файле даже упоминание про openssh есть, но оно закомментировано.

узнать месторасположение актуального файла с конфигурацией можно такой командой (приведён пример вывода):

```
$ guix system describe
Generation 1    Nov 22 2020 22:16:35    (current)
  file name: /var/guix/profiles/system-1-link
  canonical file name: /gnu/store/kjrm9syxwrs5sfmipllv8ypfpx2pssij-system
  label: GNU Guix 1.2.0-1.bd96e6d
  bootloader: grub
  root device: UUID: bd40a448-f6b1-2062-c253-4991bd40a448
  kernel: /gnu/store/7a2db6x9rjmbrfl48j1cx9zxz7czq6sc-linux-libre-5.9.3/bzImage
  configuration file: /gnu/store/cdqxpviqg1vw4ky71i63j2qq8wr30iby-configuration.scm
```

вот под заголовком «configuration file» и упомянут путь к актуальному конфигурационному файлу.

скопируйте его куда-нибудь (да хоть и в `/etc`) под произвольным именем (например, `system.scm`, чтоб самому потом понятно было, что за файл), не забудьте разрешить запись в скопированный файл для владельца (исходный файл не доступен для записи никому, с такими же правами получится и скопированный программой *cp* файл).

теперь найдите в нём упоминание про сервис openssh:

```
;; Uncomment the line below to add an SSH server.
;;(service openssh-service-type)
```

и раскомментируйте строку, убрав символы `;` в её начале (это одна из форм комментирования строки в языках *lisp/scheme/и т.п.*):

```
(service openssh-service-type)
```

а теперь примените новую конфигурацию:

```
$ sudo guix system reconfigure /путь/к/новому/файлу
```

после переконфигурации (надеюсь она, как и у меня, пройдёт успешно) можно подключаться из хост-системы (если использовали опцию `-nic user,model=virtio-net-pci,hostfwd=tcp::10022-:22` при запуске *qemu*):

```
$ ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 10022 guest@localhost
```

ах, да, пароль! по умолчанию у пользователя guest пароля нет. можно его установить программой *passwd*.