# не работает guix install

Tags: guix

скачал и запустил [qcow-образ с дистрибутивом операционной системой gnu/guix](https://mirror.yandex.ru/mirrors/gnu/guix/guix-system-vm-image-1.3.0.x86_64-linux.qcow2).

на попытку что-нибудь установить, после вывода информации о том, что будет устанавливаться, вместо начала установки выводится бесконечно одна и та же строка:

```
$ guix install openssh
...
substitute: updating substitutes from 'https://ci.guix.gnu.org'...   0.0%
substitute: updating substitutes from 'https://ci.guix.gnu.org'...   0.0%
```

почему не устанавливается ни один пакет и как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **почему**: то ли [mdc](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B0) (институт, предоставляющий сервер), то ли [cogent](https://www.kommersant.ru/doc/5240878) (магистральный провайдер), [блокируют](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-guix/2022-03/msg00004.html) доступ к ip-адресу, в который резолвятся имена `ci.guix.gnu.org` и `guix.gnu.org`, для пользователей из рф.
2. **как исправить**:

   1. разово: у программы `guix` есть опция `--substitute-urls='список серверов разделённых пробелами'`. можно указать одно или более из зеркал: [`http://ci.guix.trop.in`](https://trop.in/guix), `https://mirror.sjtu.edu.cn/guix`, `https://bordeaux.guix.gnu.org` и т.д.
   2. постоянно для дистрибутива `guix`: примеры модификации [конфигурации системы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1210780/178576) на предмет подмены substutute-urls можно подсмотреть [тут](https://bordeaux.guix.gnu.org), [тут](https://git.sr.ht/%7Ekrevedkokun/dotfiles/tree/88fa81fcef98eccf09b3fe7b224d42e0eb718598/item/config/system/yggdrasil.scm#L109), [тут](http://guix.trop.in/manual/en/html_node/Getting-Substitutes-from-Other-Servers.html), или ещё где-нибудь.
   3. постоянно для `guix` как пакетного менеджера: [надо добавить](http://guix.trop.in/manual/en/html_node/Getting-Substitutes-from-Other-Servers.html) ту же самую опцию к вызову `guix-daemon`, который обычно описан в `/etc/systemd/system/guix-daemon.service`.